# Unable to import CSV data into MySQL database with Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, import

Next piece of Python source code I use to import data from CSV file into MySql.
The installed versions in use are: MySql 5.7 and Python2.7
Furthermore, the table has 3 columns. One ID column (auto increment) and two text columns: Firstname and lastname.

The matter seems to go wrong around the SQL statement. In particular the "%s" bit.

Literally, I have done everything with punctuates like: ",' and `. E.g 's', "s", ("s") etc.

Also I have searched and used various source code snippets. All of it failed. Even I doubted the quality of my CSV file. However, importing that via e.g. MySql workbench works fine.
Ploughing my way through I managed to get data in MySql when I add for instance some  plain example values in the source code. So technically everything seems to be fine. It is just parsing which fails...

Please help. Most probably I am overlooking something simple but it drives me utterly crazy...

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import csv

db = mysql.connect(
    host = "xxxx",
    user = "xxxx",
    passwd = "xxxx",
    database = "abc"
)

cursor = db.cursor()

ifile  = open('/tmp/import.csv', "rb")
read = csv.reader(ifile)

for row in ifile:
    print row

    sql = "INSERT INTO Names(Firstname, Lastname) VALUES(%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, row)

    db.commit()

print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted")
```

What I would expect to happen is dat the data in the CSV is parsed into MySQL. 
The error message I receive is:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s)' at line 1

Thanks for any hint, clue and/or solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading the csv file correctly and you have same parameters required within the query try replacing this line

```
cursor.execute(sql, row)
```

to

```
cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. And apologies for this late reply.
The issue has become resolved in the mean time.
It has to do with my CSV file. What exactly that is, I do not know yet. However, I can continue with importing.

Thanks again and have a nice day!

Best regards,
Detlev